# Handle missing geometries in FOLIUM python

Tags: python, geojson, folium

GeoJSON comes from here

`country_geodf = gpd.read_file("https://datahub.io/core/geo-countries/r/countries.geojson")`

I am trying to create a choropleth plot using the above geoJSON data with Kaggle's 2021 ML and DS survey data. But facing these errors repeatedly. Is there any way to deal with missing geometries?

Folium can take care of missing values but not missing geometries.

---

##### Code

Snippet 1

```py
# Converting country names to ISO 3166 alpha-3 codes
cc = coco.CountryConverter()
input_countries = survey_df.Q3[1:].unique()
country_codes = cc.convert(names = input_countries, to = 'ISO3',not_found=np.nan)
country_codes = dict(zip(input_countries,country_codes))
country_names = dict(zip(country_codes,input_countries))

# Geojson with country boundaries
country_geodf = gpd.read_file("https://datahub.io/core/geo-countries/r/countries.geojson")

# Merging GeoJSON with AGGREGATED dataframe
country_df = survey_df.iloc[1:,1:]
country_df['ISO_A3'] = country_df['Q3'].apply(lambda x: country_codes[x])
country_df = country_df.groupby('ISO_A3').count()[['Q3']].reset_index()
country_df["Q3"] = round(country_df['Q3']/sum(country_df['Q3'])*100,2)
country_df = country_df.sort_values('Q3',ascending=False)
country_df = country_geodf.merge(country_df,on='ISO_A3')
```

Snippet 2

```py
country_map = folium.Map(location=[40, 0], zoom_start=1.5)

Choropleth(
    geo_data=country_df,
    data=country_df,
    columns=['ADMIN',"Q3"],
    key_on="feature.properties.ADMIN",
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=1,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Percentage of Responses",
    smooth_factor=0,
    Highlight= True,
    bins=3,
    line_color = "#0000",
    name = "Percentage of Responses",
    show=True,
    overlay=True,
    nan_fill_color = "White"
).add_to(country_map)

# Add hover functionality.
style_function = lambda x: {
    'fillColor': '#ffffff', 
    'color':'#000000', 
    'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
    'weight': 0.1
}
highlight_function = lambda x: {
    'fillColor': '#000000', 
    'color':'#000000', 
    'fillOpacity': 0.50, 
    'weight': 0.1
}

NIL = GeoJson(
    data = country_df,
    style_function=style_function, 
    control=False,
    highlight_function=highlight_function, 
    tooltip=GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['ADMIN',"Q3"],
        aliases=['Country Name',"% of Responses"],
        style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") 
    )
)
country_map.add_child(NIL)
country_map.keep_in_front(NIL)

folium.TileLayer('cartodbdark_matter',name="Dark mode",control=True).add_to(country_map)
folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron',name="Light mode",control=True).add_to(country_map)
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=True).add_to(country_map)

country_map
```

---

##### Error trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_42/729212434.py in <module>
     16     show=False,
     17     overlay=True,
---> 18     nan_fill_color = "White"
     19 ).add_to(country_map)
     20 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1291                 style_function=style_function,
   1292                 smooth_factor=smooth_factor,
-> 1293                 highlight_function=highlight_function if highlight else None)
   1294 
   1295         self.add_child(self.geojson)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, data, style_function, highlight_function, name, overlay, control, show, smooth_factor, tooltip, embed, popup, zoom_on_click, marker)
    497         self.marker = marker
    498 
--> 499         self.data = self.process_data(data)
    500 
    501         if self.style or self.highlight:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium/features.py in process_data(self, data)
    543         else:
    544             raise ValueError('Cannot render objects with any missing geometries'
--> 545                              ': {!r}'.format(data))
    546 
    547     def convert_to_feature_collection(self):

ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries:    ISO_A3     Q3                     ADMIN  \
0     IND  30.18                     India   
1     USA  10.76  United States of America   
2     JPN   3.74                     Japan   
3     CHN   3.30                     China   
4     BRA   3.05                    Brazil   
..    ...    ...                       ...   
59    KAZ   0.18                Kazakhstan   
60    NOR   0.18                    Norway   
61    DZA   0.18                   Algeria   
62    IRQ   0.17                      Iraq   
63    ETH   0.17                  Ethiopia   

                                             geometry  
0   MULTIPOLYGON (((93.85532 7.21418, 93.86500 7.2...  
1   MULTIPOLYGON (((-155.60652 20.13796, -155.5863...  
2   MULTIPOLYGON (((141.46795 24.21377, 141.46315 ...  
3   MULTIPOLYGON (((111.20460 15.77924, 111.19654 ...  
4   MULTIPOLYGON (((-48.54259 -27.81666, -48.55187...  
..                                                ...  
59  MULTIPOLYGON (((50.65952 44.93895, 50.67799 44...  
60  MULTIPOLYGON (((3.38258 -54.44931, 3.36451 -54...  
61  POLYGON ((8.60251 36.93951, 8.60566 36.91305, ...  
62  POLYGON ((42.89674 37.32491, 42.93705 37.32015...  
63  POLYGON ((38.13331 14.67776, 38.19026 14.68732...  

[64 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: please post your full code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Also sharing the link to my Kaggle Notebook - https://www.kaggle.com/kayvanshah/refreshed-insights-into-kaggle-survey-2021#Participant-from-different-countries